# Unable to name my subquery with an alias

Tags: sql-server, subquery, alias

```
select * from (
(select * FROM product_min_max_level (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN dm_Product (NOLOCK) ON product_min_max_level.Productid=dm_Product.Productid AND dm_Product.KanbanFlag=1 --AND rw=1
        INNER JOIN dm_WarehouseLocation (NOLOCK) ON dm_warehouselocation.LocationID=product_min_max_level.LOCATIONID
        LEFT JOIN ft_PickDemand_open (NOLOCK) ON ft_PickDemand_Open.PRODUCTID=product_min_max_level.PRODUCTID AND product_min_max_level.LOCATIONID=ft_PickDemand_Open.TOWAREHOUSELOCATIONID
        where dm_product.productno not in
            (select dm_product.ProductNo from product_min_max_level (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN dm_Product  (NOLOCK) ON dm_product.ProductId=product_min_max_level.Productid AND dm_product.KanbanFlag=1
            INNER JOIN dm_WarehouseLocation (NOLOCK) ON dm_WarehouseLocation.LocationID=product_min_max_level.LOCATIONID
            inner join
            (SELECT  DetailPart,GroupName,RootBOMPart,EffectiveStartDate,EffectiveEndDate
            FROM dl_MBOM (NOLOCK) ) bom2
             ON (bom2.DetailPart+bom2.GroupName)=(dm_product.ProductNo+dm_WarehouseLocation.WorkCenter)
            WHERE (product_min_max_level.Route = 77))))A1
```

I am sorry, the error that I get now is: The column 'ProductId' was specified multiple times for 'A1'.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'A1'

Comment: But is there something after A1 or before (select * ?

Comment: Hey, I edited the post. Please take a look now. After using the select statement, my error has changed to:
 The column 'ProductId' was specified multiple times for 'A1'.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
(select *
```

by

```
(select product_min_max_level.*
        , dm_Product.*
        , dm_WarehouseLocation.*
        , ft_PickDemand_open.*
```